# Trigger function periodic by datetime but not time interval

Tags: python

I want to make my function trigger at `0 second,30second`  every minute.

Rather than use `time.sleep(30)` because the script will run for months and have some blocking system call,

I want to make it happens on specific time like `12:00:00, 12:00:30, 12:01:00`

How could I do it on Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your function works but if there is any sort of a loop you could use an if statement.

```
t = time.time()

while/for loop:
    ...
    if time.time() > t + 30:
        yourFunction()
        t = time.time()
    ...
```

EDIT:

My fault, misread that. Similar method but you can use date time, probably better off looking into chrontab though. This method is a little hacky and if your script is small and can cycle every second this will work, otherwise go chrontab.

```
import datetime

t = datetime.datetime
run = True

while/for loop:
    ...
    if t.now().second % 30 == 0 and run == True:
        yourFunction()
        run = False
    if t.now().second % 30 == 1:
        run = True
    ...
```